# Relative Frequency Histogram Where Vertical Axis is Frequency Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, plotly

How do I create a relative frequency histogram plot where the vertical axis is frequency? I want it to normalize each distribution to unity and have it be relative bin to bin. The code below is for plotly. I am also interested in matplotlib solutions.

My code below creates a relative frequency graph horizantaly using Python and Plotly.

```
data = Data([
    Histogram(
        x=[x/float(114767406) for x in yp_views],
        name='Relative Frequency')])
fig = Figure(data = data)
py.iplot(fig)
```

I tried changing the x to y. Easy as that. See below.

```
data = Data([
    Histogram(
        y=[x/float(114767406) for x in yp_views],
        name='Relative Frequency')])
fig = Figure(data = data)
py.iplot(fig)
```

This makes my graph horizantal bars. I would like vertical bars with the x axis being Views and the y axis being frequency.

Answer (score 4):

The matplotlib solution is easy: use the `normed` flag:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(yp_views, bins='auto', normed=True)
```

the `hist` method calls `numpy.histogram` so you can pass options such as `bins='auto'` which are options of `numpy.histogram` and [documented there](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: `normed` is deprecated. You can use `density` instead. It makes the integral (NOT the sum) equal 1.

Comment: And if the integral (NOT necessarily the sum) is equal 1, then it is NOT necessarily relative frequencies.